# Apply a loop to a data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to apply the function `RE.Johnson` from the `Johnson` package to a whole data frame `df` that contains 157 observations of 16 variables and i'd like to loop trough all the dataframe instead of doing it manually.
I've tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
lapply(df[1:16], function(x) RE.Johnson(x))
```

I know it might seem easy for you guys but I'm juste starting with R.
Thanks

**EDIT**

R provides me the answer `Error in RE.ADT(xsl[, i]) : object 'p' not found` and the data are not transformed.
And here is a summary of the data:

```
data.frame':    157 obs. of  16 variables:
$ X         : num  786988 781045 777589 775266 786843 ...
$ Y         : num  486608 488691 490089 489293 488068 ...
$ Z         : num  182 128 191 80 131 ...
$ pH        : num  7.93 7.69 7.49 7.66 7.92 7.08 7.24 7.19 7.44 7.37 ...
$ CE        : num  0.775 3.284 3.745 4.072 0.95 ...
$ Nitrate   : int  21 14 18 83 30 42 47 101 85 15 ...
$ NP        : num  19.6 43.6 31.7 18.6 31.7 ...
$ Cl        : num  1.9 21.3 2.56 21.5 3.2 ...
$ HCO3      : num  6.65 4.85 4.4 7.72 4.1 ...
$ CO3       : num  0 0 0 0 0.0736 ...
$ Ca        : num  4.12 7.52 3.48 7.58 4.8 10 4.4 4.6 4.2 7.4 ...
$ Mg        : num  3.94 8.92 2.34 7.1 2.5 ...
$ K         : num  0.1442 0.0759 0.0709 0.3691 0.07 ...
$ Na        : num  2.41 34.55 2.51 44.01 2.1 ...
$ SO4       : num  1.45 23.6 1.2 26.66 2 ...
$ Residu_sec: num  0.496 2.102 2.397 2.606 0.608 ...
```

Comment: this is vague: " but it doesn't work." Please explain further. Is there an error? does the output differ from what is expected?  Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great R example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: With a sample of data and the error that it gives you, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: type `dput(head(df, 20))` in console, then paste the result in here to provide us with sample data

Comment: if the input is a data frame and the operations are on the column try: df[ , 1:16]

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, just some information for others.

I tried the `Johnson::RE.Johnson` manually on the columns in the `iris` data frame. It seems to be work fine for `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Length` only:

```
lapply(iris[c(1,3)], Johnson::RE.Johnson)
```

... and it returns the error you mentioned for `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Width`.

```
lapply(iris[c(2,4)], Johnson::RE.Johnson)

Error in RE.ADT(xsl[, i]) : object 'p' not found
```

This seems odd because all of those columns have a data type of `num`. The `iris` data frame doesn't appear to have any missing values or extra character values hidden anywhere, so I'm not sure why the calculation is working for those columns but not others.

Without understanding too much about what the `Johnson::RE.Johnson` is doing to the data, it looks like it is unable to calculate a value for `p` and is unable to complete the iteration for those columns.

From exploring the source code, the function appears to break down at this point:

```
  if (xsb.valida[1, i] == 0) 
    xsb.adtest[1, i] <- (Johnson::RE.ADT(xsb[, i])$p) # succeeds
  if (xsl.valida[1, i] == 0) 
    xsl.adtest[1, i] <- (Johnson::RE.ADT(xsl[, i])$p) # fails
  if (xsu.valida[1, i] == 0) 
    xsu.adtest[1, i] <- (Johnson::RE.ADT(xsu[, i])$p) # fails
```

The function attempts to run `Johnson::RE.ADT` on xsl, which at this point is a vector of just 0's. The `RE.ADT` returns the same error with the p value not being found.

Comment: Yes, i've ran the same test for my data and some columns are problematic but others not... I don't know why

Comment: Did some exploratory work on the source code for you, see above for the edit. Hopefully it will be enough for someone else to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the function try to perform the Anderson-Darling test to a vector of equals values. If you do this, you will get the error:

```
require(Johnson)
x = rep(1,n=100)
RE.ADT(x)
```

So, to solve this problem you could check it in the IF session inside the function RE.Johnson:

```
    if (xsb.valida[1, i] == 0 & any(xsb[, i]!=xsb[1, i])){
        xsb.adtest[1, i] <- (RE.ADT(xsb[, i])$p)
    }else{
        xsb.adtest[1, i] <- 0
    }   
    if (xsl.valida[1, i] == 0 & any(xsl[, i]!=xsl[1, i])) {
        xsl.adtest[1, i] <- (RE.ADT(xsl[, i])$p)
    }else{
        xsl.adtest[1, i] <- 0
    }
    if (xsu.valida[1, i] == 0 & any(xsu[, i]!=xsu[1, i])) {
        xsu.adtest[1, i] <- (RE.ADT(xsu[, i])$p)
    }else{
        xsu.adtest[1, i] <- 0
    }
```